# conditional formatting based on another value

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I need a way to conditional format cell B based on the values of cell A.

Basically I need B to be:

- Green if the values are in the same day and within the same hour of A.
- Yellow if its one hour after but within the same day, or
- Red if its past 24h of the date & time of column A.

Please, can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

These are pretty straightforward with conditional formatting.  Here's how to do the first one:

1. Select B1, and choose "Conditional formatting ->New Rule" from the style menu.
2. Select *"Use a formula to determine which cells to format."*
3. In the box that says *"Format values where this formula is true,"* enter the following:

   `=abs(A1-B1)<=(1/24)` This will return true whenever the two dates are within 1/24 of a day from each other.  It uses absolute value (`abs()`) so that it doesn't matter which one is larger.  (4:15 and 4:45 will work, as will 4:45 and 4:15)
4. Click on *Format*, then the *Fill* tab and choose a nice color of green.
5. Confirm/backout of all windows

I am not sure whether the formula in step three is exactly what you want.  It will check to see that the two date-times are within 1/24 of a day of each other (one hour).  Perhaps you mean that the actually have to be in the same hour, so that 4:01 and 4:59 match, but 4:59 and 5:01 do not?  If so, the math changes:
`=hour(A1)=hour(b1)`

For your other two conditions, you'll use some more straightforward math.  Is B1-A1 greater than 1/24?  Color yellow.  Is B1-A1 greater than 1?  Color red (The base unit of date-time in Excel is days, so `1` is 24 hours.)